# Every time I make changes on my website, my browser won't refresh and clear the cache

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a web project in PHP but I have an issue with my browser, Every time I make changes on my website, my browser won't refresh and clear the cache.

I added below code to my php page,
`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"> <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">`
If somebody trying to open that webpage in other device the recent changes were not visible without doing hard refresh.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: You need to send cache control headers to make the cache TTL short. There's no way to force caches to clear immediately when you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's solely a browser issue, you can disable caching in your browser's network settings.

1. In most browsers, use the shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`.
2. Click the `Network` tab.
3. Check `Disable cache`

See: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)